# What would be an appropriate equivalent of Jinja's macros in Django's templating system?

Tags: django, django-templates, jinja2

Let's just say that I need to render a certain amount of HTML over and over in a page, for example, for a user's profile information. Jinja's macros seem like they're absolutely fit for such usage. However, Django doesn't have macros.

Right now, I'm using a custom filter for the same purpose - is this the best way to go about it, or am I missing something?

Thanks.

---

ps. I'm migrating an app that ran on GAE with webapp2 & Jinja to Django.

Comment: Jinja extends django templates to get around some of the limitations of django's templating system. the macro's block tag is something that is jinja specific. The only way to emulate this is through (as you said) custom tags and filters, and sometimes these can get rather bulky.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some more mucking with the documentation, I finally found the ["correct" way to do this:  custom inclusion tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags), which let you create a tag out of a template.

Comment: You could just use jinja instead, if you want.

Comment: This link is dead. Here is a new one: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags

Answer (score 2):

There are two other approaches that you could take: [blocks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#block) and [includes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#include). With blocks you would have to include it all the way through the inheritance strand. With includes, you just load as necessary but you have to make sure that you're passing the appropriate context variables in from your view. However, your current approach is probably the most useful in terms of DRY.

Comment: Thanks; I just wanted to confirm. Is there any particular reason why Django hasn't picked up macros from Jinja?

Comment: @aviraldg Django's template system is not powerful by design.

Answer (score 1):

Django doesn't have macros, so it's either custom filters, or separating your repeating code in its own template, and including it over and over with different arguments passed through "with", which will probably work slower than macros. But you can actually use jinja2 templating system with django perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, I actually spent a fair bit of time adapting a pre-existing snippet to do macros in django in a fairly robust way, if you really want macros please [check it out](https://github.com/nalourie/django-macros).

As advice, most of the time what you want to do with a macro, you should really do with an include tag, as mentioned; however, sometimes you just really want a macro and for that you have to use a template tag library like mine (which is one of a few that do this for django).